# Why does Jquery mobile display mobile friendly look on desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am trying to understand Jquery mobile. I am just referring the demos and viewing it from my desktop browser (Chrome)

This is the demo link:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/forms/switch/

My question is why does the select look like it is being viewed in Ipad or something? I want the Jquery mobile to only come into action when being viewed from mobile devices. I don't want this style to be shown on my desktop computer. On desktop computer a `select` should look simple select with `options` and on mobile it should look more like what is being shown in demo (flip-flop).

Can I achieve that with Jquery mobile?

Comment: Have you actually tried using it? They most likely apply the styles no matter what so that you can see examples of what the controls would look like. Otherwise the only way you could see an example is if you went to the jquery mobile site on a device.

Comment: I think that with jQuery mobile you have two templates. One for desktop and one for mobile?

Comment: Please don't ask me questions. I am totally clueless at this point. Haha.. Creating mobile friendly websites is a pain and especially consider that I am a developer not designer

Comment: jQuery Mobile is just that, jQuery Mobile. It's for mobile devices, so it'll look like it's for mobile devices. If you want a non-mobile version then you need to create one *along with* the mobile one.

Comment: @Dave: So basically what you suggest is, create regular css and one mobile css and dynamically inject the script from my code behind (asp.net). That way I would get appropriate view? I think data-role attribute shouldn't cause problems for desktop versions as it will be simply ignored by browser.

Comment: The data- things are plain HTML5 (IIRC), so it won't necessarily be *ignored* outright, but it shouldn't have an *adverse* effect on the desktop. whether or not you can use the same HTML probably depends on the app, your needs, etc--I don't know enough to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need some kind of device recognition and routing engine for this. It doesn't really have anything to do with jQuery mobile, but rather with what backend framework you use. When I used MVC3 and jQuery mobile, I purchased 51degrees.mobi database, and then based on result of the user agent recognition I would serve different views to the user. I hope this helps.

EDIT

I think you can use 51degrees.mobi database with all asp.net projects. Basically it adds more data to Request.Browser, and then you can redirect user to either different URL or a subdomain like m.yoursite.com

```
if(Request.Browser["IsTablet"] == 'true' || Request.Browser["IsMobile"] == 'true')
{
    //redirect here
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I am using Asp.Net 4.0 vanilla and I am clueless how to build a website that looks what it should look like on desktop and changes it's look to the demo that is shown on Jquery mobile. I think I might need to do dynamic injection of javascripts and CSS after detecting user agent. How does that sound?

Comment: Oh my god, you suggest to redirect the website? This is not at all feasible and will increase too much development cost. Can't we do it using dynamic css injection? Eg. instead of redirect you wrote why not inject a mobile friend website there? using Response.Write? Is that possible or you see a downside to it?

Comment: I don't have any experience with dynamic injection, but jQuery mobile is rather complicated and it's not only CSS but also JavaScript which includes Ajax page loading. I can imagine you would have a lot of cleaning up when you do it that way. I also don't have too much experience with Asp.net forms, and I am not sure if you can serve different forms based on result of request check.